# WebPack includes entire folder (mysterious ^\.\/.*$ added) with Summernote

Tags: webpack, summernote, webpack-dev-server

Not sure why, but when importing Summernote into a build via WebPack, WebPack ends up pulling in the entire `dist` folder and thus complains that the fonts/images etc inside that folder are not valid JS.

From the webpack output, you can see that it pulls in summernotes dist js file as expected (from finding a `var summernote = require('summernote');` in a source file in my application).

```
  [149] ./~/summernote/dist/summernote.js 200 kB {1} [built]
  [150] ./~/summernote/dist ^\.\/.*$ 4.93 kB {1} [built] [5 warnings]
```

What I don't understand is where chunk `150` comes from, it's a regex that will then match every item in the `dist` folder.

WebPack has a very basic configuration, and all other items being imported function as expected.

An example of one of the many warnings:

```
WARNING in ./~/summernote/dist/font/summernote.ttf
Module parse failed: /<project>/node_modules/summernote/dist/font/summernote.ttf Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/summernote/dist ^\.\/.*$
```

**Where does chunk 150 come from, what is adding the `^\.\/.*$` requirement.**

Comment: you should mark the only response here as the correct answer. it is exactly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When webpack is resolving a module, via `require('expression')`, there will be an automatically created context. There are three types of automatically created contexts:

- exprContext: An expression as a dependency (i. e. require(expr))
- wrappedContext: An expression plus pre- and/or suffixed string (i. e. require("./templates/" + expr))
- unknownContext: Any other unparsable usage of require (i. e. require)

And the `unkownContext` has a default Regular Express will try to match files: `^\.\/.*$`;
So, for some reason, your project contains a unparseable require. When webpack is packing it, it will parse all files under a folder and try to match the `require`.

Although I still do not know which folder it will loop through, this behavior will cause your problem.

The possible solution: 
Disable the unknown `require` handling.

`javascript
 module: {
    // Disable handling of unknown requires
    unknownContextRegExp: /$^/,
    unknownContextCritical: false
 }`

[Webpack Document for refer](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories)

After the modification, my webpack process went through without problem. You can try it.

**Update**

Although above configuration can make the webpack go through, however, problem still exists. Unparseable require will cause problem in your runtime, it's better to find that incorrect require and make it right.

About the `unparseable require` in my case:

CSV.js a third party js library from NPM, it contains a following statement:

```
var s = new require('stream').Transform({objectMode: true});
```

webpack compiles it to

```
var s = new __webpack_require__(227)('stream').Transform({ objectMode: true });
```

Webpack doing **static extraction based on require**, which treats the require having no argument.

Webpack thinks the code is

```
var some = require;
var s = new some('stream').Transform({ objectMode: true });
```

while it should be

```
var some = require('stream')
var s = new some.Transform({ objectMode: true })
```

So, i rewrite this part code to

```
var stream = require('stream')
var s = new stream.Transform({ objectMode: true })
```

Problem finally solved.

So, find the invalid `require`, make it right is your only solution.

Comment: Your answer is very unclear. Please edit it to better explain what you're trying to say (and perhaps try using capital letters once in a while).

Comment: this answer totally helped me find my problem. i had an unparseable require in the form of var $= require && require('jquery') || window.$;

answer very much appreciated for helping me find this mysterious issue

Comment: Thanks for this answer - just saved me a ton of time!